# Python: Looping through files in a different directory and scanning data

Tags: python, file, loops, directory

I am having a hard time looping through files in a directory that is different from the directory where the script was written. I also ideally would want my script through go to through all files that start with sasa. There are a couple of files in the folder such as sasa.1, sasa.2 etc... as well as other files such as doc1.pdf, doc2.pdf

**I use Python Version 2.7 with windows Powershell**

**Locations of Everything**

1) Python Script Location ex: `C:Users\user\python_project`

2) Main_Directory ex: `C:Users\user\Desktop\Data`

3) Current_Working_Directory ex: `C:Users\user\python_project`

Main directory contains 100 folders (folder A, B, C, D etc..)
Each of these folders contains many files including the sasa files of interest.

**Attempts at running script**

For 1 file the following works:

Script is run the following way: `python script1.py`

```
file_path = 'C:Users\user\Desktop\Data\A\sasa.1

def writing_function(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as file_object:
        lines = file_object.readlines()

for line in lines:
print(lines)

writing_function(file_path)
```

However, the following does not work

Script is run the following way: `python script1.py A sasa.1`

```
import os
import sys
from os.path import join

dr = sys.argv[1]
file_name = sys.argv[2]

file_path = 'C:Users\user\Desktop\Data'
new_file_path = os.path.join(file_path, dr)
new_file_path2 = os.path.join(new_file_path, file_name)

def writing_function(paths):
    with open(paths) as file_object:
        lines = file_object.readlines()

for line in lines:
    print(line)

writing_function(new_file_path2)
```

I get the following error:

`with open(paths) as file_object:`
`IO Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`
`'C:Users\\user\\Desktop\\A\\sasa.1'`

Please note right now I am just working on one file, I want to be able to loop through all of the sasa files in the folder.

Comment: consider using `os.walk`

Answer (score 2):

It can be something in the line of:

```
import os
from os.path import join

def function_exec(file):
    code to execute on each file

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('path/to/your/files'): # from your argv[1]
    for f in files:
        filename = join(root, f)
        function_exec(filename)
```

Avoid using the variable `dir`. it is a python keyword. Try `print(dir(os))`

```
dir_ = argv[1] # is preferable
```

Comment: Would I be able to pass only the folder name in the argv or do I have to pass on the entire file path? Ideally, I would only like to put the folder name in the argument

I could probably have the entire path in the code all the way up to the main folder, but I would like to user to simply put the folder name for the one that contains the files.

Comment: You can use `os.path.join()` to join a base directory like the one where you have your data "2) Main_Directory ex: C:Users\user\Desktop\Data" and the directories your user inputs. Check documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=join#os.path.join

Comment: If the directory is relative to your current directory, you can use also get it by using `os.getcwd()`

Comment: Hello, I attempted to solve the problem but have found myself to be quite unsuccessful. I was wondering if you could take a look at my updated description. Thank You

Comment: Your original path, I think is missing a "\" after C: Now is 'C:Users...', shouldn't it be C:\Users...

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. Would you mind telling how I could do that now through all of the files in the folder? Each file starts with the word sasa. I would only like the argument to be the folder name, ex: A

I want the code to go through the files by itself

Comment: Did you read the documentation on `os.walk`? If you did, you'd know that the iteration on `for root, dirs, files in os.walk....` contains a lot of information: `dirs` and `files` are arrays  that you can iterate, filter, etc... If your root dir is A, the variables dirs and files will contain the complete structure of that directory A, including subdirectories, and files in each.

Comment: I did but I had a hard time understanding it, sorry. However, your explanation made it easier to understand. Thank you

Comment: A pleasure, and remember that these things that gave us problem learning, are harder to forget. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No one mentioned `glob` so far, so:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

I think you can solve your problem using its `**` magic:

> If recursive is true, the pattern “**” will match any files and zero
>   or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by
>   an os.sep, only directories and subdirectories match.

Answer (score -1):

Also note you can change directory location using

```
os.chdir(path)
```

Comment: I tried using os.chdir(folder_name) when passing the folder name into the directory. How would I pass on the entire path without knowing it?